# Why editext getText returns nothing?

Tags: android

I am developing register functionality and I need do some validation before register. So when I check is all editText null it just doesn't work. I couldn't understand why.

here the code

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    private EditText mFullName;
    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPassword;
    private EditText mPasswordAgain;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        findViewById(R.id.registerButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        mFullName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.registerFullName);
        mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
        mPasswordAgain = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordRetype);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.registerButton:

                 System.out.println("fullname="+mFullName.getText());
                 System.out.println("email="+mEmail.getText());
                 System.out.println("emailString="+mEmail.getText().toString());

                if (mFullName.getText().toString().equals("") && mEmail.getText().toString().equals("") && mPassword.getText().toString().equals("") && mPasswordAgain.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if (Utils.isValidEmail(mEmail.getText().toString())){
                        if (Utils.checkPassWordAndConfirmPassword(mPassword.getText().toString(), mPasswordAgain.getText().toString())){
                            register();
                        } else {
                            alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Error",
                                    "Password doesn't match", false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Error",
                                "Wrong email", false);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Error",
                            "All fields are required", false);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

}

You see there is System.out.println when clicking in button. I put also that here, but

```
08-01 11:34:46.830: INFO/System.out(10434): fullname=
08-01 11:34:46.830: INFO/System.out(10434): email=
08-01 11:34:46.830: INFO/System.out(10434): emailString=
```

Whe getText doesn't print null if it is empty?

Comment: you should use gettext().tostring().

Comment: No tried it doesn't work

Comment: why you need to print null?? You can do like this:
getText().toString.length() >= 1  or
if (getText().toString() != "") -- > This if empty text in edittext.

You are the first person expecting to get null!!

Comment: Your `if` statement is correct, use the checks for the `EditTexts` in the `System.out.println` and you'll get the values from the `EditTexts` in the Log.

Comment: What was the problem inside my answer that was not working to you?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Following @Pankaj Kumar answers I came to conclusion...

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mFullName.getText()) &&
                TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmail.getText()) &&
                TextUtils.isEmpty(mPassword.getText()) &&
                TextUtils.isEmpty(mPasswordAgain.getText())) { 

alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Error",
                            "All fields are required", false);
} else { 
//do another validation
}
```

I'm sure that will work.

Comment: oo Thanks that what I waiting for.

Comment: gud work! but still I am looking what was the problem in my answer.. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would check if an EditText field was empty.

```
public String checkInput(){
    email= username.getText().toString();
    if(email.equals("")){
        System.out.println("No email");
    }
 }
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a logical error in your original code:

```
if (mFullName.getText().toString().equals("") && mEmail.getText().toString().equals("") && mPassword.getText().toString().equals("") && mPasswordAgain.getText().toString().equals("")){
```

This code if true means that all the text fields were empty and the user should be shown the alert dialogue here about `"All fields are required"`.

whereas in your current code you was showing that alert in the `else` part of your code. Which is logically wrong.